# Swastika Symbol in HTML

Tags: html, symbols

This is just simple question, I've searched it in google, and found nothing about how to simply write swastika symbol using HTML. Anyone here can help me how or the reference sites? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/534d/index.htm

Comment: You could go ask the Third Reich's web development department.

Comment: Thanks bmargulies , that help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<html>
   <body>
       &#21325;
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just visited link gave by  bmargulies above and found it.

Comment: That's not the swastika. That's the nazi symbol. The real swastika is a mirror image of this with dots inside.

Answer (score 0):

It is reversed swastika right is unicode “卐” (U+5350) clockwise not anticlockwise hindu jain budhist symbol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).